# Have you any idea what such a question is deemed?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, questions

What does making an interrogative sentence with the verb "to have" used as a verb and an auxiliary at the same time sound like? Old-fashioned? Snobbish? Spoken English only? Ungrammatical?

Comment: What do you mean?  "He had the measles." -> "Has he had the measles?"

Comment: Can you please give some examples of what you're talking about?

Comment: Haven't you any idea what I'm talking about?

Comment: Where you would expect: "Don't you have any idea what I'm talking about?" or "Haven't you got any idea what I'm talking about?"

Comment: "Have you no idea what I am talking about?"  For interrogative, we generally put the "have" auxiliary before the subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Have" as an auxiliary always patterns as an auxiliary ("have you seen", "I haven't seen" etc).

"Have" as a full verb can pattern either as an auxiliary ("Have you any?" "I haven't any") or as a normal verb ("Do you have any?" "I don't have any").

In American English, "do" support is more common with it, and I believe that questions and negatives without it  are seen as rather formal or old fashioned.

My observation is that British English has changed in my lifetime (60 years). When I was young "Have you ... " or "Have you got ... " and "I haven't" or "I haven't got" were normal, and "Do you have" and "I don't have" were something that we simply wouldn't say unless we meant it in a habitual sense ("Do you have dances in your village?")

A look at google ngrams shows that in the US "I haven't any" started to decline sharply in around 1945, while "I don't have any" rose steadily from about 1930, and surpassed "I haven't any" in 1960. In Britain the pattern is similar, but 10-20 years later: the lines crossed around 1975.